# Z3 in place of CVC3

Tags: z3

CVC3 is used to get value assignments satisfying constraints. I have been trying to check the feasibility of replacing the use of CVC3 with Z3. For example, if there are department records like *department* record = [NAME, SALARY] and following constraints:
1. SALARY > 100 and SALARY < 1000
2. NAME can be one of {abc, def, ghi}

The primary aim is to generate records satisfying some constraints for relations in database.

How can these constraints be specified using Z3 to get possible value assignments to the department records? Is the SMT lib format input file sufficient or should I be looking at the programmatic APIs exposed by Z3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found a way to do it.

(declare-datatypes () ((S abc def ghi)))
(declare-fun NAME () S)
(declare-fun SALARY () Int)
(assert (and (> SALARY 100) (< SALARY 1000)))
(assert (or (not (= NAME abc)) (= NAME def) (= NAME ghi)))
(check-sat)
(get-value (NAME))
(get-value (SALARY))

Now the above model will return:

sat
((NAME ghi))
((SALARY 101))

Comment: Very nice solution.  Congratulations.  All the best.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution is as follows

```
(declare-sort S)
(declare-fun abc () S)
(declare-fun def () S)
(declare-fun ghi () S)
(declare-fun NAME () S)
(declare-fun SALARY () Int)
(assert (and (> SALARY 100) (< SALARY 1000)))
(assert (or (= NAME abc) (= NAME def) (= NAME ghi)))
(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

The corresponding output is

```
sat
```

Please run this example online [here](http://rise4fun.com/Z3/ElpEq)

Comment: How to get the particular value assignments satisfying the constraints? I can get the SALARY value using get-value((SALARY)). What about NAME value?

Comment: Using the command `get-value` we obtain



((NAME S!val!1)) 
((abc S!val!0)) 
((def S!val!1)) 
((ghi S!val!2))

Then  NAME = def .

Do you agree?

Comment: (get-value (NAME)) returns ((NAME S!val!1)). How do we make out the actual value from that? Sorry, if it sounds stupid. I am new to Z3 and SMTLib.

Comment: Your question is very interesting because "by hand" I know that NAME= def, but I do not how to derive it automatically.

Comment: I think I have worked around it. Please check the answer posted.